# Symbol ! in haskell in front of a variable name in a function

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

What does symbol ! in front of a variable name in a haskell function mean? For example

```
let f !x = x + 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: That question already has a very good answer, I would also say it's a duplicate.

Comment: agreed, will mark this as solved. Thanks!